# How can I point an object to a certain point in Box2DJS + Cocos2DJS

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, mousemove

I'm trying to simulate an archery shooting game and I want to animate the bow to point where my mouse is. How can I do this? I already tried binding a joint and using this for mouse follow:

```
this.bow.SetTransform(new b2Vec2(x/30, y/30), this.bow.GetAngle());
```

but it always comes up with an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'GetAngle'

I already searched for the error but it was not found in Google. Is there a way to fix this or another way to implement the bow-mouse follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of the `SetTransform` method looks like this:

```
 b2Body.prototype.SetTransform = function (xf) {
      this.SetPositionAndAngle(xf.position, xf.GetAngle());
 }
```

Try calling `SetPositionAndAngle` instead of `SetTransform`